Next.js - ReferenceError: window is not defined
Facing while experimenting with device orientation
Here is the code, I am using
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 export default function App() {
   const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);

 useEffect(() => {
  function handleResize() {
  setIsLandscape(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
 }, []);

 return (
   <div>
  {isLandscape ? <Landscape /> : <Portrait />}
   </div>
);
}

And for your reference, here is the last and related question, I posted on SO
Calling functions as per device orientation
Experiment # 1
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {

        const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);

....

}

getting :
This resolved that issue, but showing the new one
Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>.

Final code
export default function App() {
        
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {

        const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);

         useEffect(() => {
          function handleResize() {
            setIsLandscape(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
          }

          window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
          return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
         }, []);

         return (
           <div>
            {isLandscape ? <Landscape /> : <Portrait />}
           </div>
        );
        
    }
        
}

Complete error says:
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error


This question is similar to: Window is not defined in Next.js React app. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I would go through the Next.js docs. Next.js provides a server and client side. You're not seeing this due to this file being a server side. See here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components

@ndisn if you have already tried the things listed in that post, edit your question to include exactly what you tried and why it didn't work. As it stands, it does not appear that you have implemented any of those solutions.

I never wanted to confuse others, as I am beginner, my implementation might be wrong or may be not so good to understand, may be not that much clear, hence I though just share the code working and the issue I am facing... if you still feel I have not given try please let me know, I won't mind sharing what I tried @asportnoy

@ndisn, we are providing guidance from seniors, part of the learning process is to read documentation or review stack overflow posts from already asked questions. Please update your question with the solutions you've tried. Number them and provide more context per each attempt.

@RogerPerez please check an update, I posted one of the solutions, I tried but facing another issue

Fun JS fact: don't use the DOM-only window, use the JS built-in globalThis, which maps to window in the browser, but unlike window is a JS language-level reserved keyword and so won't cause errors just by being in your code.

The part of your code that is actually causing the issue is the useState(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight). That is run in both the server and the client and is what is giving you the "window is not defined" error.
Your approach to wrapping everything in the typeof window !== "undefined" check doesn't work because it does not return anything at all when run server side. It is theoretically possible to make that approach work by adding a return value when it is server-side, but there is a better solution:

Set a hard-coded default value for isLandscape to allow for it to run server side
Move setting the real initial value for the client to the useEffect handler. useEffect is only run client side so you can access window here without issue.

By doing this, we've moved all the code that needs the window to client side code, and set appropriate defaults so the page can run server side while still returning a component as expected.
export default function App() {
    const [isLandscape, setIsLandscape] = useState(true); // <-- Changed to just true, you can use false if you prefer.

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            setIsLandscape(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
        }
        handleResize(); // <-- Added, sets initial value right away once loaded in the browser

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, []);

    return <div>{isLandscape ? <Landscape /> : <Portrait />}</div>;
}


amazing... great explanation...  you the master.... thanks a lot

If you are using app router, add "use client" at the top to tell it it's a client component so it has access to window.

I am already using that... "use client";

@ndisn Oh didn't notice you have window in your state's initial value. Like asportnoy said that's the issue, because you are trying to access it before your component mounts that way. FYI, do not use hook conditionally https://react.dev/reference/rules/rules-of-hooks#:~:text=Don%E2%80%99t%20call%20Hooks%20inside%20loops%2C%20conditions
